# Aproximating a point to a region fill in Plotly Scatter Region Fill

Tags: python, numpy, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly.graph-objects

I am using plotly with Python, and I am trying to approach a point to the nearest region boundary considering either x or y axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def plot_graph5(points_x, points_y):   
    fig = go.Figure()
    
    dx = np.array([[0,129,129,330,1594,1977,1977],[0.93,0.93,0.58,0.58,0.43,0.25,0]])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(dx.T, columns=['x','y'])
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2.x, y=df2.y, fill='tozeroy')) # fill to trace0 y

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=points_x, y=points_y, mode='markers', marker=dict(size=8))) #fill to trace0 y
    
    fig.show()
    
points_y = np.array([0.65])
points_x = np.array([730])

plot_graph5(points_x, points_y)
```

[image: Resulting graph]

I was trying to choose either x or y value and determine the nearest value. For example, If I choose the x point, make it return the corresponding y value that would make the point intersect the region. Is it possible using just plotly? Using a button or similar?

Answer (score 0):

This really is a geometry operation, snapping a point to a line. Hence have used **shapely** to perform the geometric operations.   This is use of [linear referencing](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#linear-referencing-methods)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import shapely.geometry


def plot_graph5(points_x, points_y):
    fig = go.Figure()

    dx = np.array(
        [[0, 129, 129, 330, 1594, 1977, 1977], [0.93, 0.93, 0.58, 0.58, 0.43, 0.25, 0]]
    )
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(dx.T, columns=["x", "y"])

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2.x, y=df2.y, fill="tozeroy"))  # fill to trace0 y

    snap_x = []
    snap_y = []
    ls = shapely.geometry.LineString(dx.T)

    for x, y in zip(points_x, points_y):
        p = ls.interpolate(ls.project(shapely.geometry.Point(x, y)))
        snap_x.append(p.x)
        snap_y.append(p.y)

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=points_x, y=points_y, name="raw", mode="markers", marker=dict(size=8)
        )
    )  # fill to trace0 y
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=snap_x, y=snap_y, name="snapped", mode="markers", marker=dict(size=8)
        )
    )  # fill to trace0 y

    fig.show()

points_y = np.array([0.65, 0.63])
points_x = np.array([730, 1100])

plot_graph5(points_x, points_y)
```

[image]